# Django Tests fail with InternalError: no such savepoint. DB: Postgres, passes on mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

Interestingly it also works on the shell.

```
   [MY code which calls Model.objects.get_or_create(...)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 123, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 308, in get_or_create
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 199, in savepoint_rollback
    connection._savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 67, in _savepoint_rollback
    self.cursor().execute(self.ops.savepoint_rollback_sql(sid))
InternalError: no such savepoint
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test code that uses transactions, you'll need to subclass [`TransactionTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#django.test.TransactionTestCase) instead of `TestCase`

for example:

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase

class MyTests(TransactionTestCase):
    ...
```

It probably passes in MySql because you're using MyISAM tables which don't support transactions